# Writing data into same chanel from different go routines is working fine without wait group

Tags: go

When writing data into same channel using multiple go routines with waitgroup after waiting wg.Wait() getting exception saying all go routines are asleep  or deedlock.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func CreateMultipleRoutines() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // creates 10 go routines and adds to waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                ch <- j
            }
            wg.Done() // indication of go routine is done to main routine
        }()
    }

    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
    wg.Wait()           //wait for all go routines to complete
    close(ch)           // closing channel after completion of wait fo go routines
    for v := range ch { // range can be used since channel is closed
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println("About to exit program ...")
}
```

When tried to implement this without waitgroup I am able to read data from channel by looping exact number of times  data pushed to channel but i cant range since there will be panic when we close channel. here is the example code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)


    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // creates 10 go routines and adds to waitgroup
        go func(i int) {
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                ch <- j * i
            }
        }(i)
    }

    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())

    for v := 0; v < 100; v++ {
        fmt.Println(<-ch)
    }
    fmt.Println("About to exit program ...")
}
```

I want to understand why waitgroup in wait state is still waiting even though all go routines are signalled Done() which inturn makes number of go routines to zero

Comment: Have you seen your last example does not print out the list of the `int`s you add to the channel? That is because you close the channel before running the loop. Then, you will get the all go routines are asleep DEADlock again. That is because there is no goroutines running ad ch will never be changed again.

Comment: As a general rule, go-routines that write to a channel should be the one to close the channel. Closing while not coordinating with other go-routines, will guarantee a panic when they write to a closed channel.

Comment: @colminator this is not the case with multiple writers, because each writer does not know if *all* writers are finished. Hence the use of `WaitGroup` and closing the channel from outside the writers.

Comment: @JamilloSantos yes you are right I have updated the code correctly now

Comment: @Adrian this Q has gone through several code edits - the version I saw had a main go-routine closing a channel and uncoordinated with the completion of other go-routines.I think we're on the same page - even with multi-writers the _manager_ of the writers should close the channel - and not the main (reader) go-routine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `chan` *holds* no items, so all go routines are blocked on sending, until something reads from it. They never actually reach the `wg.Done()` statement.

A solution would be to close the channel in it's own go routine. Wrap your `wg.Wait()` and `close(ch)` lines like this:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait() //wait for all go routines to complete
    close(ch) // closing channel after completion of wait fo go routines
}()
```

Then you can range over the channel, which will only close after all of the sending go routines have finished (and implicitly all values have been received).

Comment: That is one option but I would not go that way.

Comment: I agree, it's not ideal, hence the word "workaround" with the caveat about best practice. See the update.

Comment: @Adrian, I agree with you that the first is not the proper solution to the problem, I was simply illustrating _why_ the OP was getting a deadlock.

Comment: @TravisHegner I have tried out your solution and it is working fine and I have accepted your answer. I just wanted to check whether my understanding is correct, when we are creating a separate go routine(lets routine X) for wait group wait and close channel this separate routine is waiting instead of main routine hence main routine will start receiving values sent to the channel from multiple routines created in first for loop, once all go routines are completed and x routine will start resuming and closes channel which will stop range from reading channel.

Comment: @BhanuReddy yes, that is correct. The sending go routines can only continue because the main routine is able to read the values off of the channel simultaneously, and the channel must remain open until the sending routines are finished. A buffered channel could increase throughput and reduce context switching in a real world scenario.

Comment: `By default a chan only _holds_ 1 item`; no, by default a channel is unbuffered, and _holds_ nothing.

Comment: @JimB that is more technically correct, indeed. I will update.

Answer (score 2):

I think your original code has some problems.

1. You are closing the channel before reading from it.
2. You are not getting the advantage of using 10 goroutines because of your channel is 1 "sized". So one goroutine is producing one result per once.

My solution would be to spawn a new goroutine to monitor if the 10 goroutines finished its jobs. There you will use your `WaitGroup`.

Then the code would be like:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int, 10)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // creates 10 go routines and adds to waitgroup
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            for j := 0; j < 10; j++ {
                ch <- j
            }
            wg.Done() // indication of go routine is done to main routine
        }()
    }

    go func(){
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    fmt.Println(runtime.NumGoroutine())
    for v := range ch { // range can be used since channel is closed
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
    fmt.Println("About to exit program ...")
}
```